# IF not exists not working properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a problem with a SQL Server stored procedure. I am trying to check if there is already data with the same id in both tables.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Objective_Comment_Insert]
    @CompanyName AS NVARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM dbo.[SB$Objective Comment] oc, [dbo].[comments] cc
                   WHERE CONVERT(INT, oc.[Employee No_]) = (SELECT u1.employee_no 
                                                            FROM c0_intranet.dbo.users u1 
                                                            WHERE u1.user_id = cc.user_id) 
                     AND oc.[No_] = cc.comment_id)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.[SB$Objective Comment]([Comment By], [Comment], [Date Created],
                                               [No_], [Comment On], [Employee No_])
            SELECT  
                (SELECT u1.employee_no 
                 FROM c0_intranet.dbo.users u1 
                 WHERE u1.user_id = cs.user_id
                ),
                CASE 
                   WHEN cs.comment IS NULL 
                      THEN '' 
                      ELSE cs.comment 
                END,
                CASE 
                   WHEN cs.date_created IS NULL 
                      THEN FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-dd') 
                      ELSE FORMAT(cs.date_created, 'yyyy-MM-dd') 
                END,
                cs.comment_id,
                CASE 
                   WHEN cs.comment_on IS NULL 
                      THEN 0 
                      ELSE cs.comment_on 
                END,
                (SELECT u1.employee_no 
                 FROM dbo.users u1 
                 WHERE u1.user_id = cs.user_id)
            FROM 
                dbo.comments cs
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE NAV_2017.dbo.[SB$Objective Comment]
        SET [Comment By] = (SELECT u1.employee_no 
                            FROM dbo.users u1 
                            WHERE u1.user_id = cs.user_id),
            [Comment] = CASE 
                           WHEN cs.comment IS NULL 
                              THEN '' 
                              ELSE cs.comment 
                        END,
            [Date Created] = CASE 
                                WHEN cs.date_created IS NULL 
                                   THEN FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')  
                                   ELSE FORMAT(cs.date_created, 'yyyy-MM-dd') 
                             END,
            [No_] = cs.comment_id,
            [Comment On] = CASE 
                              WHEN cs.comment_on IS NULL 
                                 THEN 0 
                                 ELSE cs.comment_on 
                           END,
            [Employee No_] = (SELECT u1.employee_no 
                              FROM dbo.users u1 
                              WHERE u1.user_id = cs.user_id)
        FROM dbo.comments cs, NAV_2017.dbo.[SB$Objective Comment] oc
        WHERE 
            CONVERT(INT, oc.[Employee No_]) = (SELECT u1.employee_no 
                                               FROM dbo.users u1 
                                               WHERE u1.user_id = cs.user_id)
            AND oc.[No_] = cs.comment_id 
    END
END
```

When it is executed for the first time, there is no data in second table and it works after I add another record in first table it doesn't insert it into second table but there is no errors.

[This is when I execute the procedure inside exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KSRF.png)

[This is data from table comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1YKX.png)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: sql 2012. It is product specific. I have a problem in exists part of my procedure. And i can't configure why

Comment: What records do you see when you execute just that SELECT statement that's inside that EXISTS?

Comment: I see data that have the same employee_id and comment_id/[No] in both tables @HansKesting

Comment: the way you are writing your queries is very hard to read, why are you not using `join`, are all the subqueries in `insert` really needed?

Comment: Yes it is needed cause i use two different databases

Comment: in sql server you can write joins between databases residing on the same server

Comment: man that thing is working, i have a problem with exists. It really doesn't matter. But thanks for your advice. @avb

Comment: Have you tried running the SQL (no need to wrap it in a stored proc) in SSMS?  Can you include PRINT statements at various points to check the flow / see what's going on.

Comment: I posted an answer, but it took me too long, check if it is proper

Comment: @JohnLBevan i tried it but it always say (6 row(s) affected) and i have 7 rows

Comment: Is the issue that there is at least 1 record which matches your "if exists" condition, but you were hoping to apply this logic per record?  i.e. for those records which don't have a comment you want to insert a new comment, for those which do you want to update it?

Comment: yes,  that is what i want to do. To check for every record if it is in second table to update it if not to insert it. @JohnLBevan

Comment: Cool; in that case can you amend your question to state what tables you have and what your aim is; as the current code is quite a long way off, and from the code given it's not entirely clear which server each database catalog sits under.

Answer (score 0):

If I properly reconstructed your logic, this query is equal to yours:

```
select 1
from [dbo].[comments] cc
    join c0_intranet.dbo.users u1 on u1.user_id = cc.user_id
    join dbo.[SB$Objective Comment] oc on oc.[No_] = cc.comment_id and CONVERT(int, oc.[Employee No_] = u1.employee_no
```

and if so, it will always return rows if there is any data already copied to `dbo.[SB$Objective Comment]`, try replacing with this:

```
select 1
from [dbo].[comments] cc
    join c0_intranet.dbo.users u1 on u1.user_id = cc.user_id
    left outer join dbo.[SB$Objective Comment] oc on oc.[No_] = cc.comment_id and CONVERT(int, oc.[Employee No_] = u1.employee_no
where oc.[No_] is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is wrong here and you should be looking at a trigger rather than a procedure. Specifically I think you have inserted 6 rows to comments, executed the procedure then inserted another row to comments and then another execute of the procedure. The problem is that at the first call the exists test fails (ie it does not exist) so comment is inserted. On the second call the exists test passes (6 records do exist) so the insert is not done. The procedure cannot know what has been inserted to comments which is why a trigger (which does know what has been inserted) would be my choice together with a suitable exists test for insertion into comment.

Comment: You are right, i decided to solve this on another way. I used a MERGE command so it is working now.